# symfony2 500 Internal Server Error

Tags: symfony

I am trying to code my homepage, but get a 500 Internal Server Error. Funny thing, the echo test works, so the template rendering seems to fail somehow.

my routimg.yml:

```
klik_core_homepage:
    path:     /
    defaults: { _controller: KlikCoreBundle:Homepage:index }
```

my HomepageController

```
namespace Klik\CoreBundle\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;

class HomepageController extends Controller
{
    public function indexAction(Request $request)
    {

    $twigParams = [];
    //echo "test";

    return $this->render('KlikCoreBundle:Homepage:index.html.twig', $twigParams);       
   }
}
```

Edit:
I found the second route to /, its in AppBundle\Controller\DefaultController and uses annotation in stead of yml, like the rest of my setup.

```
//AppBundle\Controller\DefaultController
/**
* @Route("/", name="homepage")
*/
```

changed it to

```
/**
* @Route("/old", name="homepageold")
*/
```

sudo app/console router:debug result:

result

klik_single_zoek                  ANY      ANY    ANY  /zoek
   klik_core_homepage                ANY      ANY    ANY  /
   klik_profiel_inschrijven          ANY      ANY    ANY  /inschrijven
   klik_profiel_inschrijvensubmit    ANY      ANY    ANY  /inschrijven/create
   klik_profiel_edit                 ANY      ANY    ANY  /profiel/aanpassen
   login                             ANY      ANY    ANY  /login
   login_check                       ANY      ANY    ANY  /login_check
   homepageold                       ANY      ANY    ANY  /old
   fos_user_security_login           ANY      ANY    ANY  /login
   fos_user_security_check           POST     ANY    ANY  /login_check
   fos_user_security_logout          ANY      ANY    ANY  /logout
   fos_user_profile_show             GET      ANY    ANY  /profile/

But unfortunately its not the cause of 500 error since its still there after cache:clear.

Comment: If you're in dev mode Symfony should display more than a 500 error - if not check your logs.  That code in and of itself isn't bad, although you typically pass a key/value array of parameters to your templates.  Please post the exact error message you're receiving - 500 doesn't offer much help.

Comment: No, nothing in cache/logs/dev.log or in my apache.log

Comment: Btw, if change the routing path to /home, then it works.

Comment: Are you in dev mode?  That doesn't make a lot of sense

Comment: Yes, I am, I get the dev footer on other working pages and also error pages when I type a faulty slug.

Comment: Do you have the AcmeDemoBundle still installed?  If so make sure that's no longer there - it already has a route to "/" defined that could be causing a conflict.

Comment: Have you tried cleaning your cache, for your current environment? (`php app/console cache:clear --env=dev`)

Comment: No AcmeDemoBundle, I do have a AppBundle but that one is a critical part I believe. Also did the cache:clear command. Unfortunately no success.

Comment: btw do have some errors in the dev.log now:                        [2014-12-26 21:19:36] security.DEBUG: Write SecurityContext in the session [] []
[2014-12-26 21:19:36] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.response" to listener "Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Firewall\ContextListener::onKernelResponse". [] []
[2014-12-26 21:19:36] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.response" to listener "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener

Answer (score 0):

I have found the the problem, the route to / goes to app.php instead of app_dev.php just like Jason suggested. So I peaked in app/dev/prod.log and found a bunch of errors to faulty routes in the menu (have to find out whats wrong with them). 
So disabled the menu and all is fine. 
On top of my htacces I still had 
    DirectoryIndex app.php 
changed it to 
    DirectoryIndex app_dev.php

All thanks for the clues !